# How can I declare something in a TypeScript module typing without exporting it?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, definitelytyped

I'm writing typings for a package to contribute to DefinitelyTyped, so the file I'm creating will be resolved in module context.  This is simple enough, along the lines of

```
import { A } from "package-a";
export function B(): void;
```

However, I'd like to declare a few types and interfaces that are not useful to consumers of the package, but make the declarations easier to read and write:

```
type ArgType = string | ArrayBuffer | Uint8Array | Readable | ReadableStream;
export function foo(x: ArgType): void;
export function bar(x: ArgType): string;
export function baz(x: ArgType): number;
```

The problem is, as soon as I declare `ArgType` at the top level, it's actually exported from the module along with `foo`, `bar`, and `baz`. This means `ArgType` shows up in the language service for auto-complete, etc, which looks messy.  It also happens with interfaces and namespaces.

`dtslint` has an error for this, [`strict-export-declare-modifiers`](https://github.com/Microsoft/dtslint/blob/master/docs/strict-export-declare-modifiers.md), which is how I first discovered this behavior.  As far as I can tell, this isn't a problem when writing an actual TS module (vice a declaration / typings file).  Is it not possible to declare something in this file that the consumer won't see?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know to do this is to declare a namespace with your intended exports, use an export assignment to make that namespace the top-level export, and then put your auxiliary definitions outside the namespace:

```
type ArgType = string | ArrayBuffer | Uint8Array | Readable | ReadableStream;
declare namespace Exports {
    function foo(x: ArgType): void;
    function bar(x: ArgType): string;
    function baz(x: ArgType): number;        
}
export = Exports;
```

I'm not sure this is considered recommended practice (does anyone know?), and you lose the ability to declare a default export.  IMO, if you thought a type or interface was useful to write the declarations, it is bound to be useful to someone, somewhere, writing a wrapper for the library, so I would just export it.

### Update 2018-09-30

By accident, Luke Pighetti [discovered](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52582848) a real solution: including at least one `export {...}` statement, even an empty one, suppresses the default behavior of exporting all symbols even if they aren't marked `export`.  [According to andy-ms](https://github.com/Microsoft/dtslint/issues/138#issuecomment-426028292), this is supported TypeScript behavior.

```
type ArgType = string | ArrayBuffer | Uint8Array | Readable | ReadableStream;
export function foo(x: ArgType): void;
export function bar(x: ArgType): string;
export function baz(x: ArgType): number;
export {};
```

Comment: This does solve the problem I was trying to address -- the unhelpful shorthand I didn't want to expose is not visible to the consumer.  However, using `export = SomeNamespace` triggers the dtslint violation [`export-just-namespace`](https://github.com/Microsoft/dtslint/blob/master/docs/export-just-namespace.md). Basically, dtslint wants you to declare a module at the top level and not "hide" it in a namespace. I'm going to ask on their tracker for clarification.

Comment: [Question is up](https://github.com/Microsoft/dtslint/issues/138), we'll see if anybody on `dtslint` has a suggestion.  Maybe the linter is wrong!