# def file for object export and types

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Alright, so we have a Node module `string-similarity` who exports two functions like this (see: https://github.com/aceakash/string-similarity/blob/master/compare-strings.js#L7-L8 )

```
module.exports = { compareTwoStrings, findBestMatch }
```

I have put together a definition file that works quite well, except I cannot access the types.

```
declare module "string-similarity" {
  function compareTwoStrings(string1: string, string2: string): number;

  function findBestMatch(string: string, targetStrings: string[]): Result;

  interface Result {
    ratings: Match[];
    bestMatch: Match;
  }

  interface Match {
    target: string;
    rating: number;
  }

  export { compareTwoStrings, findBestMatch };
}
```

I am very new to Typescript so my question is this: should I be able to import these types? I would think so. And also, is there an idiomatically correct way to create this def file?

### Update

I was able to get the intellisense in VSC to think I had solved the problem, but I still get the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'compareTwoStrings' of undefined`. Even though I can see the methods just fine and no red squiggles.

### index.d.ts

```
declare module "string-similarity" {
  namespace similarity {
    function compareTwoStrings(string1: string, string2: string): number;

    function findBestMatch(string: string, targetStrings: string[]): Result;
  }

  export interface Result {
    ratings: Match[];
    bestMatch: Match;
  }

  export interface Match {
    target: string;
    rating: number;
  }

  export default similarity;
}
```

### string-similarity.spec.ts

```
import similarity from "string-similarity";
import { Result, Match } from "string-similarity";

describe("compare two strings", () => {
  it("works", () => {
    const string1 = "hello";
    const string2 = "dello";

    const result: number = similarity.compareTwoStrings(string1, string2);

    expect(result).toBe(0.75);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access your methods under a common parent (*e.g.* `similarity`), you need to import them under the `similarity` alias:

```
import * as similarity from "string-similarity"; 

similarity.compareTwoStrings("potato", "tomato");
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `export { ... }` line is limiting the exports.  (I was unaware that it is possible to do that in a `declare module` block!)  If I delete that line, then by default everything is exported and I'm able to access the types.

Comment: Hey Matt, the problem with that approach is I cannot use the methods as `similarity.compareTwoStrings()`. Trying to do something like `import similarity from "string-similarity"` and also be able to access the types.

Comment: @LukePighetti You should be able to achieve that by `import * as similarity from "string-similarity";`

Comment: OK, I see now. Thank you.

Comment: @LukePighetti I've added it as an answer, feel free to accept it if it solved your problem.