# Intentional that `export {}` shuts off automatic export of all symbols from a TypeScript module declaration?

Tags: typescript

In a TypeScript external module declaration (either an entire `.d.ts` file or a `declare module` block in another file), by default, all symbols are exported even if they are not marked `export`.  Luke Pighetti [discovered](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52582848) that adding an `export { ... }` statement suppresses this behavior, so that only symbols marked `export` are exported.

Example `my-module.d.ts`:

```
export const a = 1;
declare const b = 2;
export {};
```

`consumer.ts`:

```
import { a } from "./my-module";  // OK
import { b } from "./my-module";  // Error
```

This behavior is potentially useful.  Is it intentional, or a TypeScript bug that I should report and not encourage people to rely on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[andy-ms says](https://github.com/Microsoft/dtslint/issues/138#issuecomment-426028292) the behavior is intentional.  (But it's undocumented AFAIK, like so many advanced TypeScript behaviors. :( )

I tracked down [the compiler code](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/dd9b8cab34a3e389e924d768eb656cf50656f582/src/compiler/binder.ts#L1571-L1592) that is involved.  The full list of constructs that shut off automatic export:

- `export { ... }`
- `export { ... } from "module"`
- `export * from "module"`
- `export = ...`
- `export default` of an expression, but not `export default` of a function, class, or interface definition

Answer (score 0):

This is intentional.

A TypeScript file can be either a script file or a module file.
The differentiation between the to is that module file has at least one top-level import/export.

When a file is a module file, only the code explicitly exported with the `export` keyword would be available.

For a script file, it is treated as if it is part of the global, meaning your content will be available in other files.

For typings file (`*.d.ts`), in DefinitelyTyped they are written as script file with the format of `declare module x { ... }` to define the typings for a specific module.

It is written that way in DefinitelyTyped because it is a repository of many modules, and the tooling needs to know which module it is defined for.

If you create a typings file for a JavaScript library and distribute it with that library, it will be written as a module file(s).

Comment: When `export {}` is removed, `my-module.d.ts` still has a top-level export, so no, what I'm seeing isn't the usual distinction between global scripts and external modules.